# What is the best way to design the Kafka messaging for java based application?

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka, spring-xd

How to decide for between different framework  for implementing kafka messaging over rest api. (For achieving production level usage)

1) Kafka java client to design class to send /receive messages/events.
2) Spring integration kafka api to be used as a separate micro service.
3) Spring-xd and Kafka.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.confluent.io/blog/how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-the-schema-part-1/ and http://www.confluent.io/blog/schema-registry-kafka-stream-processing-yes-virginia-you-really-need-one

Comment: I finally decided to write a small framework using pure Kafka Java client and a wrapper Rest API which invoke my framework API to Send/Receive Message.